# Bulk rename image assets with Excel

Tags: image, excel, rename, file-rename, vba

I have images stored on an image server

I download all the images on PC (ExtremePictureFinder software)

Now I need to rename them. (AdvancedRenamer Software)

I have this excel file:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CMStYrw.png]

I need to have the old image name to be the new image name

However, some images are duplicated when they get saved to my PC. So the old image names are thus instead:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dRftVco.png]

How would I go fixing this?  I can only think of three ways:

1. Make the old image name reflect whats actually downloaded (the difference between 2 images, see highlighted area) using excelVBA or excel functions
2. Have some method for downloading each image asset one at a time and rename, so no duplicate file names when bulk download + bulk renaming  (Scripting?)
3. Download all unique image assets. Then have something to duplicate new image assets + new image name (possibly using a script or 3rd party program)

Comment: How many ways do you need?  Why not try one of those three?

Comment: I only need one way. I put down 3 potential solutions that would work, none of them being things I figured out how to do yet

Answer (score -1):

You can try an open source alternative like excel parser processor, it downloads all the items on column and renames if you supply a value to rename on another column, if not supplied file name remains the same.